# Multi line substitution duplicating across lines in OSX

Tags: sed, osx

I'm a little rusty in my `sed` and haven't used it much since moving to a Mac but I am aware there seems to be a difference with what `sed` is used on a Mac per Ubuntu after a few searches.  What I am trying to do is replace the first part on an XML file with some new values.  After refreshing my knowledge on `sed` I decided to use:

```
sed -e '1,/<\/value>/ s/.*/\<something\>lorem ipsum\<\/something\>\n\<again\>wednesday\<\/again\>\n/' $theFile
```

when I run the code it outputs `<something>lorem ipsum</something>n<again>wednesday</again>n` on all the lines from the 1st line up to where `</value>` ends.

So my question is what is the appropriate way to replace the contents of the file on its desired new line without duplicating it on every line?

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` is **line**-editor so it apply script to each line wich addressed. So you should collect lines which you'd like to exchange in one string with `n`ewline separator(s):

```
sed -e '1{:1;N;/<\/value>/b1;s/.*/\<something\>lorem.....\n/}' $theFile
```

Other way is to `i`nsert necessary text before block then remove the block:

```
sed -e '1i\\<something\>lorem.....\n' -e '1,/<\/value>/d' $theFile
```